# Combining @Embeddable with @MappedSuperclass in one entity in JPA (EclipseLink)

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

After switching to EclipseLink 2.6.0 (from 2.5.2), for a domain class declared with

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Embeddable
public class ADomainClass { ... }
```

I get an error:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [default] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.EmbeddableTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MappedSuperclassTypeImpl
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:231)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.EmbeddableTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MappedSuperclassTypeImpl
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.preInitialize(MetamodelImpl.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.<init>(MetamodelImpl.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.<init>(MetamodelImpl.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.preInitializeMetamodel(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:3755)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2000)
    ... 71 more
```

Is it possible this is an unwanted regression in this new version of EclipseLink?

(Note that when I look at the `ClassCastException` I can see in the same stack frame, it is caused by my class `ADomainClass`.)

**EDIT:**

My use case is an inheritance between *Embeddables*. 
My superclass `ADomainClass` (which is `@Embeddable`) and is extended by another `@Embeddable` class `ASubtype` does not work, unless the superclass is annotated with `@MappedSuperclass`.

According to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables#Inheritance, *EclipseLink* / *Toplink* supports this JPA non-standard feature. Though one should achieve it with `DescriptorCustomizer` and the `InheritancePolicy`. (And not with `@MappedSuperclass`?)

Comment: Your class cannot be both an Embeddable and a mappedSuperClass.  This might have went through with only warnings before while now it seems to be having problems with the Metamodel processing, though I can't say without the full stack and knowing if you have metamodel classes to process.  Regardless, you need to decide if this class is an entity's superclass or if it is an embeddable class on its own.

Comment: To be honest, I still think it makes sense to have a class annotated with both. I went through the whole JPA Spec but without any success. Would you please link me to a paragraph that says (or implies at least) it is not allowed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seven years later, no one can! Everyone has strong opinions until you say "here is the reference/standard, show me where it says or doesn't say _xyz_."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with @Chris's comment, I'm not sure how it ever worked for you, or what would be the purpose of such class. `@MappedSuperclass` and `@Embeddable` serve a completely different purpose.

`@MappedSuperclass` is used to group some common properties used by all entities, like `id`, or some auditing information like `createdAt` and `createdBy`. From JPA 2.1 spec:

> [2.11.2] Typically, the purpose of such a mapped superclass is to define state
>   and mapping information that is common to multiple entity classes.

In short, mapped superclasses are to be extended by entities. Entities can also extend non-entity classes, but in that case the superclass isn't persisted, only behavior is inherited. Also, all annotations on such classes are ignored.

> [2.11.3] The non-entity superclass serves for inheritance of behavior only. The state of a non-entity superclass is not persistent. Any state inherited from non-entity superclasses is non-persistent in an inheriting entity class. This non-persistent state is not managed by the entity manager[23]. Any annotations on such superclasses are ignored.

`@Embeddable` is used to group/embed some properties of an entity in a separate class, which can also be reused in other entities. All the fields of embeddable class are mapped to columns in the owning entity, except if `@ElementCollection` and `@CollectionTable` are used for storing them. The JPA specification does not define inheritance for embeddables (though EclipseLink supports it by use of its native API) [EclipseLink Doc](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Embeddable#Inheritance). They can also contain mappings to other entities (from JPA 2.0). Nevertheless, they are not intended to be extended by entities. From [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables)

> Generally attempting to mix inheritance between embeddables and entities is not a good idea, but may work in some cases.
>   
> ...
>   Relationships to embeddable objects from entities other than the embeddable's parent are typically not a good idea, as an embeddable is a private dependent part of its parent. Generally relationships should be to the embeddable's parent, not the embeddable. Otherwise, it would normally be a good idea to make the embeddable an independent entity with its own table.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in a good direction. As I updated my question, my problem is an inheritance of classes annotated with `@Embeddable`.

Comment: Yes, looks like with EclipseLink you have to use `DescriptorCustomizer` and the `InheritancePolicy`. Unfortunately, I've never done this myself so I can't help you with the implementation, but take a look at [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/239667/) for some samples.

Comment: About inheritance of embeddable objects, I did read that link about JPA not supporting it but I later ran into examples of it working. Can't find them now but if I do I'll edit my answer with references. Thanks.